# SSH from client to embedded linux through server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

I want to be able to directly connect from anywhere to an embedded linux (called C) which doesn't have a public IP address.

C can set up a connection to the server (with SSH -R), and if I SSH into the server, I can then SSH into the embedded linux.

However, I'd like to be able to SSH from client to C without having to first SSH into the server. (I can't set up a connection with SSH -R from C to client)

Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily. One way is to use SSH's remote port forwarding, by which C is telling the server to forward a port back to it, something like:

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 server
```

This command, when run from C, will tell the server to take any connection to port 2222 and forward them to C on port 22.

Likewise, you could set up port forwarding on the server via firewall rules.

Comment: No. This will still listen on `localhost`, which is obviously not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to connect to the forwarded port, you need four things:

- Specify the server public IP/hostname as the first argument to `-R`, otherwise it will be listening only on `localhost`, which is obviously not accessible from outside of the server.
- Configure the server with `GatewayPorts`, which will allow the forwarded ports to be accessible from outside
- Use the `-g` switch to basically allow the same from client side
- Open the port `2222` in the server firewall.

The command can look like this:

```
ssh -g -R server:2222:localhost:22 server
```